# Putting Jquery script tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, script-tag

I got error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function` in `show.html.erb`. Popover is in my navbar, and `show.html.erb` has jquery plugin(bxslider). I put my script tag `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` on my head of `show.html.erb` like,

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
  <script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
  <link href="/css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

When I erase `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` , error disappears but my plugin does not working.
My popover works well in other pages, and my plugin looks like this. It's on my bottom of `show.html.erb`.

```
<script>

  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

  var realSlider= $j("ul#bxslider").bxSlider({
        speed:1000,
        pager:false,
        controls: true,
        nextText:'<span></span>',
        prevText:'<span></span>',
        infiniteLoop:true,
        captions: true,
        onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
          changeRealThumb(realThumbSlider,newIndex);

        }

      });

      var realThumbSlider=$j("ul#bxslider-pager").bxSlider({
        minSlides: 8,
        maxSlides: 8,
        slideWidth: 100,
        slideMargin: 12,
        moveSlides: 1,
        pager:false,
        speed:1000,
        controls: true,
        infiniteLoop:false,
        hideControlOnEnd:true,
        nextText:'<span></span>',
        prevText:'<span></span>',
        onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){

        }
      });

      linkRealSliders(realSlider,realThumbSlider);

      if($j("#bxslider-pager li").length<5){
        $j("#bxslider-pager .bx-next").hide();
      }

// sincronizza sliders realizzazioni
  function linkRealSliders(bigS,thumbS){

    $j("ul#bxslider-pager").on("click","a",function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var newIndex=$j(this).parent().attr("data-slideIndex");
          bigS.goToSlide(newIndex);
    });
  }

//slider!=$thumbSlider. slider is the realslider
  function changeRealThumb(slider,newIndex){

    var $thumbS=$j("#bxslider-pager");
    $thumbS.find('.active').removeClass("active");
    $thumbS.find('li[data-slideIndex="'+newIndex+'"]').addClass("active");

    if(slider.getSlideCount()-newIndex>=4)slider.goToSlide(newIndex);
    else slider.goToSlide(slider.getSlideCount()-4);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: makes no sense to use noConflict inside of a ready method

Comment: Please don't care about that one. I write `$(document).ready(fucntion(){ });` not to be loaded javascript code before DOM is loaded.

Comment: Anyway I fix it, Thanks! @epascarello

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all put all of you js file into app/assets/javascripts and css in app/assets/stylesheets

Change your path for the file in :

```
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
  <link href="/css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
  <link href="/assets/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or you cal also include these file into application.js and application.css.scss like this :

in application.js file

```
//= require jquery.bxslider.min.js
```

and in application.css.scss file :

```
 *= require jquery.bxslider
```

Comment: Are there any reasons to do that? I think it's better way to use `Public`, but don't know why.

Comment: I read [asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and understand what you saying.  But I still got same problem. @Jai Kumar Rajput

Comment: okay , Try to change the order of the script tags , Hope it will work for you. Some time I have got same problem and I solved by changing the order.

Comment: May be in your application.js file //= require_tree is not at the last of all other it should be like :

//= require pages.js
//= require tables.js
//= require uielements.js
//= require_tree.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I changed my order, and it works. Thank you1

Comment: Mention not :) enjoy ruby :P